# How to select nearest div of select element in parents Untill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<div id="installation-table">
 <div class="row bg-info installation-product-item-row form-group m-t-5" data-install="0"><div>
 <div class="row bg-info installation-product-item-row form-group m-t-5" data-install="1"><div>
 <div class="row bg-info installation-product-item-row form-group m-t-5" data-install="2"><div>
</div>
```

Inside each div I have input field and select picker ,

If am changing some value in input field , i need to pick the select picker value of exact div it is inside ,

but everytime selectpicker value is taking the select picker value inside the first div(data-install="0")

```js
 $(document).on('change', '.installation-product-qty', function (e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var index = $(this).parentsUntil('.installation-product-item-row').parent().data('install');
                var room = $(this).parentsUntil('.room-table').parent().data('room');
                installation[index].qty = Math.ceil($(this).val());
                var conversion_rate = $(this).parentsUntil('.installation-product-item-row').find('.installation-product-item-measurement option:selected').data('conversion_rate') // always taking first value 
            });
```

Snap for more details

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```html
<div id="new-installation-product" class="hidden">
    <div class="row bg-info installation-product-item-row form-group m-t-5">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2"><label class="installation-product-name"></label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="row m-t-5">

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control installation-product-item-area">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <select class="form-control simple installation-product-item-measurement " data-live-search="true">
                        <?php foreach ($measurements as $measurement): ?>
                                <option value="<?= $measurement->getId() ?>"><?= $measurement->getName() ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!--                <div class="col-sm-4 text-right col-lg-4">
                                    <span class="installation-product-box-qty"></span>
                                </div>                -->
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 text-right">
            <!--            <label class="installation-product-qty"></label>-->


            <input type="text" class="form-control installation-product-qty installation-product-qty-change">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control installation-product-price">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select class="form-control installation-qty-closed-stock-unit-label  m-0 simple" disabled="disabled"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 installation-item-tax m-t-5">
            <select class="installation-product-tax form-control simple" data-live-search="true">
                <option value="">Select</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1  text-right"><label class="installation-product-amount"></label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `.installation-product-qty` in HTML? Share that too

Comment: Is you html code complete mentioned here.....

Comment: no not completely .

Comment: .installation-product-qty  is inside the div

Comment: Where are the `input` and the `selectpicker` ? Please add their code to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('change', '.installation-product-qty', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).parent().find(".installation-product-item-measurement  option:selected").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="installation-table">
  <div class="row bg-info installation-product-item-row form-group m-t-5" data-install="0">
    <input class="installation-product-qty" type="text" />
    <select class="installation-product-item-measurement">
      <option>1</option>
      <option selected>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-info installation-product-item-row form-group m-t-5" data-install="1">
    <input class="installation-product-qty" type="text" />
    <select class="installation-product-item-measurement">
      <option>1</option>
      <option selected>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-info installation-product-item-row form-group m-t-5" data-install="2">
    <input class="installation-product-qty" type="text" />
    <select class="installation-product-item-measurement">
      <option>1</option>
      <option selected>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```